# Что лучше использовать в качестве первичного ключа в PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Что лучше использовать как первичный ключ в Postgres? Слышал мнение что serial не очень безопасно так как дает потенциальным злоумышлиникам понять сколько в таблице записей хранится.

Comment: А есть что-то небезопасное в знании количества записей в таблице?

Comment: Это от сущности зависит, безопасно ли это. И от того, какой доступ вы к ней представляете.

Comment: Как я вам уже написал к предыдущему вопросу - не хотите показывать реальные id из БД клиенту - не показывайте, шифруйте их. Но БД не должны касаться ваши взаимоотношения с клиентом

Comment: Можете использовать тип данных `UUID`.

Comment: @etki Некоторые сайты так пытаются защититься от тотального парсинга: количество записей неизвестно, какой будет ID у следующей непонятно. Да вы поди не видели, как защищаются от попыток узнать пользуется ли данный пользователь сервисом (был ли зарегистрирован емейл пользователя).

Comment: @AK security through obscurity

Comment: @etki прям как с кредитными картами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с SQL базами данных довольно глубоко проникает и закрепляется мнение, что у каждой записи должен быть свой автоинкрементный ключ. От этой мысли стоит избавляться по ряду причин, в первую очередь потому, что никакой необходимости у записи в идентификаторе-счетчике, конечно, нет. Можно взять классический пример с чатом:

```
messages:
| id | chat_id | user_id | message   |
|  1 |       1 |       1 | Hello     |
|  2 |       1 |       3 | ...World! |
```

Эта схема встречается довольно часто, но, на самом деле, она не несет никакого смысла:

- Сообщение однозначно определяется чатом, в который оно было отправлено, и временем/порядковым номером *внутри этого чата*, а не каким-то порядковым номером внутри потока всех сообщений. Сообщение не имеет смысла среди всех остальных сообщений, но имеет смысл внутри контекста конкретного чата
- При простых имплементациях у сообщения вообще нет первичного ключа. Если сообщение нельзя пересылать / удалять / изменять, то и ссылаться на него тоже не нужно, и оно имеет лишь атрибут принадлежности к чату и атрибут для сортировки

Кроме того, автоматический инкремент имеет еще одну неприятную сторону - он требует синхронизации. Перед созданием новой записи кто-то должен проинкрементировать счетчик, убедиться, что никто не сделал это же в параллель, и отдать идентификатор клиенту. В SQL-серверах с единственным мастером это никогда не было большой проблемой, но любая распределенная система, на которую может захотеться перейти, этого не выдержит и в лучшем случае просто оставит с низким потолком масштабируемости.

Поэтому первичный ключ следует искать в самой сущности. Чаще всего у сущности и так есть главный атрибут, по которому на нее можно ссылаться - никнейм для пользователя, почтовый адрес у непосредственно почтового ящика, артикул у товара. Такие идентификаторы, которые называются натуральными, как правило еще и легче вбивать (нежели искать, под каким числом записан тот или иной пользователь), хотя здесь, конечно, нельзя забывать и про доменную область приложения: если пользователь в теории может сменить свой никнейм, то идентифицировать его стоит по какому-то другому признаку.

Если первичный ключ не удается выделить из самой сущности, то стоит прибегнуть к суррогатному ключу. Выше уже порекомендовали UUID, который хорош тем, что имеет крайне низкую вероятность коллизии и (в зависимости от версии) может монотонно возрастать со временем и содержать в себе идентификатор машины (как правило, mac-адрес) (что автоматически гарантирует отсутствие коллизий при разных идентификаторах машин, однако это не дает гарантии, что клиент не придет повторно со вставкой такого же айдишника - если это какой-то плохой клиент). В случае, если UUID по каким-то причинам не подходит, можно взять любой другой источник случайных значений, но стоит проявлять особую осторожность при вставке записей (какая-нибудь SQL-база данных не позволит при коллизии переписать старую запись, а условная Cassandra - только в путь); есть [прекрасная статья](https://medium.com/@betable/tifu-by-using-math-random-f1c308c4fd9d) с классическим TIFU в заголовке о том, как прострелить себе ногу, если просто надеяться на то, что рандом как-нибудь сам разрулит коллизии.

Вопросы безопасности с выбором первичного ключа никак не связаны, и, при необходимости, первичный ключ может быть обфусцирован, что и вовсе сводит на нет подобные заботы.

Comment: мда получается не такая простая это задача может оказаться выбор первичного ключа особенно если сущность типо юзера, ник и пароль может поменяться и емайл тоже, даже номер паспорта, а автоинкремент с многопоточностью проблемы вызывает. Рандомы по ногам стреляют прям линия фронта))) кроме UUID получается ничего и не остается?

Comment: @Павел если выкинуть случай с переходом на распределенное хранилище, автоинкремент не такая и плохая штука. Единственное что к нему нужно относиться к какому-то случайному значению, а не последовательному счетчику.

Comment: В случаях распределенной системы автоинкремент из секвенса может отлично работать, если на каждой системе выдавать id начиная с собственного стартового значения, при этом с шагом в количество серверов.

Comment: @Mike я посмотрю как вы будете добавлять ноду

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой способ использовать `UUID` в качестве `PRIMARY KEY`.

Плюсы:

- по значению нельзя определить число записей в таблице;
- значения можно генерировать как в базе, так и на клиенте, так как они
  будут всегда уникальны.

Минусы:

- `UUID` занимает 16 байт, для сравнения `INT` 4 байта, а `BIGINT` 8
  байт;
- в Postgres, насколько мне известно, нет аналога функции
  `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` как в MsSQL. Это значит, что новые значения могут
  попадать в любое место индекса, что потребует дополнительные затраты
  его обслуживание.

Так же можно посмотреть в сторону использования `INT` или `BIGINT`. В этом случае придется делать отдельный механизм генерации случайных значений, которых еще нет в таблице.